# Swagger client generation

Tags: javascript, npm, swagger, swagger-codegen

I have a `npm`-based project and I want to introduce `swagger`-based REST API client into it. My idea is to have API description `yaml` file and generate client on build step.
Is there any well knows approaches to do it? I found only `swagger-js-codegen` but I don't clearly understand how to integrate it into building process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you've your REST API documented in Swagger/OpenAPI spec, you can then simply use `curl` (or other http tools) to send an HTTP request to generate API clients as part of your build process. An example of the curl request to generate ruby client for `http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json` is as follows:

```
curl -X POST -H "content-type:application/json" -d '{"swaggerUrl":"http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json"}' https://generator.swagger.io/api/gen/clients/ruby
```

Please refer to https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#online-generators for more info.

UPDATE: On May 2018, about 50 top contributors and template creators of Swagger Codegen decided to fork Swagger Codegen to maintain a community-driven version called [OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator). Please refer to the [Q&A](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/qna.md) for more information.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without hitting the internet? Our operations team isn't too keen on the idea of depending on a third party like swagger.io to be up for our CI-build to pass.

Comment: You can download the JAR instead as mentioned in the project's README: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen